# Loop through input elements and get all ids that starts with 'value_'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementById("value_[0-9]"))
    {
        alert('found: ' + inputs[i].value);
    }
    else
    {
        alert(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

I'm using the condition to get only input IDs that starts with `value_`

```
if (document.getElementById("value_[0-9]"))
```

but nothing is true where I have 5 or more IDs in my form. i.e. value_1,  value_2, value_3 etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) with [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make it an *Array*

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="value_"]'));
```

From here you can do your favorite loop, e.g. [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 5):

You use wrong method for that. Simply check the `id` property of a certain element in the list:

```
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].id.indexOf("value_") === 0) {
        // alert("Found: " + inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' ), function( input ) {
    return input.id.indexOf( 'value_' ) === 0;
}).forEach(function( input ) {
    // do whatever here
});
```